# How to replace a number of random characters with sql in a string?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

My code is (not working):

```
update wp_posts 
set post_excerpt = replace(post_excerpt, 'https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=****************&amp;w=154&h=154&amp;url=', '');
```

Where the **************** is 16 random letters (big and small). 
I'd like to remove it from everywhere.

Thank you very much!

Edit:

I found a nice app that can do this: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: What do you mean "16 random letters"?  Can you provide sample data and the results you want?  Within a given `post_exercpt` can the string appear more than once?  If multiple occurrences are allowed, would they all have the same 16 characters?

Comment: Sample data:
`<img src="https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQAatQXRgSAEGISt&amp;w=154&amp;h=154&amp;url=http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-SBXH7EohF2k/U-JitrZZZkI/AAAAAAAArEg/7ldLEoTFRuE/s1600/20140806_190645%255B1%255D.jpg"`

           

         Results I want: 
`<img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-SBXH7EohF2k/U-JitrZZZkI/AAAAAAAArEg/7ldLEoTFRuE/s1600/20140806_190645%255B1%255D.jpg"`

Comment: The URL itself is changed between the sample and results?

Comment: no it's not, only the first part is deleted, but the d=AQAatQXRgSAEGISt can be any characters, other parts of the url is the same.

Comment: Other example:
`<img src="https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQA996I_OLGi14U9&amp;w=154&amp;h=154&amp;url=https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t31.0-8/q84/s720x720/10453095_670072739750956_4366453943458090356_o.jpg"`

to: `<img src="https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t31.0-8/q84/s720x720/10453095_670072739750956_4366453943458090356_o.jpg"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ought to do it, just replace @strg with whatever you are referencing the string by (column/variable name).

```
'<img src="https://' + (RIGHT(@strg,LEN(@strg)-(CHARINDEX('url=http',@strg)+10))) + '>'
```